# c++ substr Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I tried this simple example in Visual studio 2008 Forms environment:

```
String^ textn;
textn = this->dateTimePicker1->Value.ToString();
textn = textn.substr(0, 7);
```

This did not compile with the cryptic message:

```
1>        type is 'System::String ^'
1>        did you intend to use '->' instead?
```

I have googled for about 1 hour now finding out why it fails but I just cannot find an answer. I usually code C# but due to situation at work I have to downgrade to C++ and I find it VERY hard to do the simplest things.

Comment: That looks suspiciously like a mixture of Pascal and C++.

Comment: "I have to downgrade to C++" `<joke>`Ouch! How's using a superior language is a "downgrade"?`</joke>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems in your code: first is accessing members of managed classes; second is the names of the members that you access.

When you use managed types, the members that you access remain the same as in C#. When you use a C++ `std::string`, you can use `substr`. When you use `System.String`, you need to use `Substring`, like this:

```
textn = textn->Substring(0, 7);
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not very cryptic. It tells you what to do. Use `->` instead of `.` to access a member of a managed pointer:

```
textn = textn->substr(0, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you are mixing "C++" with "C++/CLR". "C++/CLR" stands for C++ Common Language Runtime, which is basically what .NET uses.

When you want to store a variable you now have three ways of doing it.

```
std::string    value1; // This is allocating a variable on C++ stack
std::string*   value2; // Allocating on the C++ heap.
System.String^ value3; // Handle to object on managed heap (CLR).
```

A simple rule to remember is that when it is on a heap you need an arrow.

For more information about handle to object on managed heap see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/yk97tc08(v=vs.110).aspx